# What is the ideal MySQL transaction isolation mode for an e-commerce site?

Tags: mysql, transactions, e-commerce, relational-database

What is the best transaction isolation mode for an e-commerce site that has to do the typical run-down of database operations for subtracting inventory? Should I be using `READ COMMITTED` to protect against reading in-transaction data?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the data to be accurate or not ?  And exactly *how* accurate do you want it to be ?  And exactly how much guarantee do you expect from the system that your data will indeed be accurate ?

On a scale from zero to 100%, 100% means that you should use SERIALIZABLE, and zero means that you can afford (/your user can accept) READ UNCOMMITTED.

EDIT (following suggestion in comment)

But of course the stronger guarantees regarding data integrity come at a price.  At the very least, "stronger" isolation levels (SERIALIZABLE, REPEATABLE READ) will always leave less opportunity for update transactions to run concurrently.  They **might** also be responsible for less concurrency between updaters and readers.  No hard and fast universal rules, depends on the internal mechanisms that the engine uses.

Comment: Probably you should also explain the downsides of using `SERIALIZABLE`, as it is not obvious why you shouldn't always go with it.